# Whats is the use of annotation group in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am new to doctrine, In my symfony project all the entity annotation linked with groups but **I am not getting what is the use of Groups.**

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Groups({"public","details"})
     */
```

I have newly added the field in my entity file, while executing the schema update getting (newly added field) was never imported.

What is groups and how it's useful.

Answer (score 4):

Groups is not part of doctrine, and is not necessary unless you need serialize objects to use json or xml (Rest API, etc)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-serialization-groups

Answer (score 1):

It allows to serialize just selected group of attributes (eg. to skip internal ones).

Read more here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-serialization-groups